# Can't seem to add summation in while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, double, variable-assignment, integer-arithmetic

I was making a code that adds a summation for a specific formula, but the sum is always 0 for some reason. What is the reason nothing is adding? I think maybe it is the declaration of int and double for the variables. When I do a simple equation, such as adding natural numbers, it works, but not for more complicated equations like the one below.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, n;
    double sum = 0;
    printf("Enter the max value for the sum: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    i = 1;

    while(i <= n)
    {
        sum = sum + (1 / ((1 + i) * (1 + i)));
        i++;
    }
    printf("Sum = %f\n", sum);  
}
```

I tried the code pasted above, expected the correct sum, but resulted in only 0.0000.

Comment: `sum = sum + (1.0 / ((1 + i) * (1 + i)));`

Answer (score 1):

In this statement

```
sum = sum + (1 / ((1 + i) * (1 + i)));
```

the sub-expression `(1 / ((1 + i) * (1 + i)))` uses the integer arithmetic. It means that if to divide `1` by any integer number greater than `1` the result will be equal to `0`.

Consider this simple demonstration program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int i = 1;

    i = i / 2;

    printf( "i = %d\n", i );
}
```

Its output is

```
i = 0
```

You need to use the arithmetic with float numbers.

It will be enough to write

```
sum += 1.0 / ((1 + i) * (1 + i));
```

Or it will be even more better to write using `long long int` constant `1ll` within the expression like

```
sum += 1.0 / ((1ll + i) * (1ll + i));
```

to avoid overflow for the integer multiplication.

Also as the range is specified as two positive numbers then it will be logically better to specify the variables `i` and `n` as having the type `unsigned int`.

Comment: Would it make sense to declare all variables as a double? I know it increases the user input range to input decimals, but just hypothetically speaking.

Comment: @BeansAndRice The range is specified as two integers.:)

Comment: Oh, so doing double i = 1; double = n; scanf("%f", &n); wouldn't work since the original input (let's say n = 5) were integers even if they were declared as double?

Comment: @BeansAndRice I think  that according to the assignment the range is specified as a pair of integers.

Comment: @BeansAndRice `double = n; scanf("%f", &n);` should use `%lf`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the result of the divison as a double since that is what you are expecting as a result. Int division will round it to closest whole number

Comment: Casting the result is too late, you need to force the operation to be done with floating point numbers.